# Django Query Joining and Grouping

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'm having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to query the following scenarios and appreciate any assistance

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class DatapointModel(models.Model): 
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

Now I essentially need all company that have two valid DatapointModel rules such as companies with both

```
datapoint name='country' with value='USA'
```

and

```
datapoint name='building_color' with value='blue'
```

Results I'm looking for: company name where both datapoint rules are satisfied. This would be easy if I had both the country and building_color stored in the Company object but since I have so many datapoints I don't want to structure my model that way and I'm kind of stuck on how to query it with django

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Checkout Djangos built in ```.filter()``` attribute.

You can pass ```name``` and ```value``` to the filter and it will give you the objects that have the values you pass to the filter.

Comment: @Kyvex thanks man but the issue is I need to filter on multiple name and value pairs not just one so a simple filter does not work in this case. I need something like

`qs1 = DatapointModel.objects.filter(name='one', value__gt=1)`
`qs2 = DatapointModel.objects.filter(name='two', value__gt=2)`
`results = qs1 | qs2`
where qs1 and qs2 have the same company that they reference as a foreign key

Comment: Ah okay. I misread your question. I'm curious if a ```Q Object``` would do the trick for you.

```Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')```

Checkout Djangos Query Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: I've tried just about everything I could figure out to try from the documentation and have went down that route before asking the question, only asked because I was still stuck. Tried Q Object implementations. Any complete example of it would would be appreciated. The best I've been able to get is results which have one datapoint or the other case valid but not both. Need both cases to be valid. Like I said that would be super simple if I didn't normalize the structure of the data, but since I did normalize the models I can't figure out how to achieve this result

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, your filters would simply be:

```
Company.objets.filter(
    datapointmodel__name="building_color", 
    datapointmodel___value="blue"
)
```

You probably want some logic in there to make your name/value pairing work in a sensible way.

Comment: Thanks but how would I get that plus the other datapoint for country using an AND. Thus company1 with building_color blue and country USA

Comment: You would need to use a Q object which can handle AND and OR https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q

Comment: yeah that always returns no results for me though because the Q object is looking at the datapoint model which can't have two names and that is the only way I can figure out how to write it. Do you have an example of the full solution?

Comment: It could have two names if you have an AND and then an or, like this: `Q(dpm__name="building_color")&Q(dpm__value="blue") | Q(dpm__name="country')&Q(dpm__value="USA")` - I've tested it on some of my own code and it works perfectly. If you still aren't getting the results you want then consider whether just have a name/value model for such diverse information is suitable

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I tried that same approach a few days ago.. the issues with your recent suggestion is it could return 1 company that matches the case of building_color blue and a 2nd company with country in usa.. but I only want companies that satisfy BOTH requirements.

Comment: In that case you probably want to make a queryset from your valid data points which can easily filter for color, country, etc. and then call something like `.filter(datapointmodel__in=dpm_queryset)` on your other model